# I am getting a message whenever I connect my database in oracle 12c 'Your password is soon going to expire'. How do I change the password?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Will the connection still work after I change my password?

Answer (score 1):

Once you are logged in, use the command

```
ALTER USER user_name IDENTIFIED BY new_password;
```

to change your password. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4003.htm#SQLRF01103)

Replace `user_name` with your user name.